# Bad view of a long table

Tags: longtable, datatool

I dont know why this works bad on the last line.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={nom,ape}]{miembros}{miembros.csv}

\begin{document}

\justifying
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm} | p{5cm}|}
    \hline 
     &  \\
    \makebox[7cm][c]{Nombre} & \makebox[5cm][c]{Firma} \\ & \\ 
    \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Continua en la siguiente p\'agina} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    \DTLforeach{miembros}{\nom=nom,\ape=ape}{& \\ \ape, \nom & \\ & \\ \hline}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

miebros.csv

```
Javier;Delgado Cruces
Manu\'el Andr\'es;Espuelas Cifuentes
Enrique Mart\'in;Garcia Mart\'in
Alejandro;Lobato Cantos
Ana;Mart\'in Prieto
```

Output

[image: table]

Comment: `\\ & \\ \hline` creates an empty row which includes the column rules. Are you using that to increase the vertical spacing? If so, there may be a better way around it that doesn't cause the problem.

Comment: Please provide a complete example and don't leave people to try guessing how they need to complete the document to produce the output shown.

Comment: Really sorry, i think nowyou have all that you need to produce the output.

Comment: the example (and your posted answer) produces `! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \DTLsetseparator` also `\justifying` is not defined (and if I guess its definition it would have no effect on longtable)

Comment: I forgot the ragged2e package, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to put `\\` at the start of the `\DTLforeach` loop to avoid interference:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={nom,ape}]{miembros}{miembros.csv}

\begin{document}

\justifying
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm} | p{5cm}|}
    \hline 
     &  \\
    \makebox[7cm][c]{Nombre} & \makebox[5cm][c]{Firma} \\ & \\ 
    \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Continua en la siguiente p\'agina} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    \DTLforeach{miembros}{\nom=nom,\ape=ape}{%
      \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\\hline}% start new tabular row
      & \\
      \ape, \nom & \\
      & 
    }
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of table]

Incidentally, you might want to consider a different way of applying the vertical spacing, as you may encounter some problems from it. On the first iteration of `\DTLforeach` there are three tabular rows:

```
& \\ 
Delgado Cruces, Javier & \\
& \\ \hline
```

All three fit on the page, and so on, but if the table reaches the end of the page the page break may occur before or after `\ape, \nom & \\` which means you have a blank row either at the end of the page or at the start of the next page, which leads to an odd effect. It's better to remove those blank rows and increase the vertical height of the remaining rows.

You can redefine `\arraystretch` or you can add an invisible rule to increase vertical spacing. Here's a simple document for comparison:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
 & \\
A1 & A2\\
 & \\\hline
 & \\
B1 & B2\\
 & \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Continued}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
A1 & A2\\\hline
B1 & B2\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Continued}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}% reset

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{8ex}A1 & A2\\\hline
\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{8ex}B1 & B2\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Continued}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of three tables]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `\kill`, but i think is not the best.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={nom,ape}]{miembros}{miembros.csv}

\begin{document}

\justifying
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm} | p{5cm}|}
    \hline 
     &  \\
    \makebox[7cm][c]{Nombre} & \makebox[5cm][c]{Firma} \\ & \\ 
    \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Continua en la siguiente p\'agina} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    \DTLforeach{miembros}{\nom=nom,\ape=ape}{& \\ \ape, \nom & \\ & \\ \hline}
    \kill
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

miebros.csv

```
Javier;Delgado Cruces
Manu\'el Andr\'es;Espuelas Cifuentes
Enrique Mart\'in;Garcia Mart\'in
Alejandro;Lobato Cantos
Ana;Mart\'in Prieto
```

Output

[image: table]